# Android - Handing Fragments during Backpress

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have,   `Fragment A` that contains *listView* - by the time the user clicks an item the current view will be replaced by  another view that also contains a listview called `Fragment B`.

Fragment A -> B, I manage to add Fragment A to backstack so when the user is in `Fragment B`, if he press the back button it will go back to `Fragment A`. The problem is after I press Again `Fragment A`(*listView*) it will just display a bank screen and I expect that `Fragment B` should be displayed again.

**Fragment A**

```
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                //FragmentActivity  activity =  getActivity();

                    String fragMainGroups = "mainGroups";

                    Fragment videoFragment = new VideoPlayerFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, videoFragment, fragMainGroups );
                    transaction.addToBackStack(fragMainGroups);
                    transaction.commit(); 

            }
        });
```

**Edit**

```
                String fragMainGroups = "mainGroups";
            String Groups = "Groups";

                Fragment fragment1 = new VideoPlayerFragment();


                /*FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment1, fragMainGroups );
                transaction.addToBackStack(fragMainGroups);
                transaction.commit(); */

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.addToBackStack(Groups);
                ft.add(R.id.contentFragment, fragment1, fragMainGroups);
                ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
    transaction.add(R.id.contentFragment, videoFragment, fragMainGroups );
```

an extra reminding:

you'd better use getSupportFragmentManager, this will be better compatibility.

Comment: I edited my question above. I am still getting the same senario. Its like when I click `Fragment A`, it will open a blank View...0_T

Comment: I can see any problem in your posted code. is any problem in your fragement B?

Comment: `Fragment B` has no interaction, by the time that I reaches `Fragment B`view, i just backpressed right away to have `Fragment A`-displayed again, after which I clicked again A but no `Fragment B` displayed for the second time.

Comment: what is your fragment b like?

Comment: `Fragment B` is the same as `Fragment A`- it contains a listView that gets data from the database. Every time `Fragment A`(listview) is clicked it opens `Fragment B`(queries the database and displays its own listView). Both of them has their own `onCreateView`. The returned query from `B` has data and I printed it in logcat to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to handle back button press through your activity unless your actvity host large number of fragments.When you press back button inside your fragment onBackPressed() method of your activity will be called which can be overridden and handled..So in your case handling back button for fragments can be done in this way..You can update it accordingly

MainActvity

```
     public static boolean isMainActivityShown ;
     public static boolean isFragment1FromMainActivity=false ;
     public static boolean isFragment1FromFragment2=false ;
     public static boolean isFragment2Shown=false ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        isMainActivityShown=true  //inside onCreate method put isMainActivityShown true
. 
. 
.
}
.
.
Fragment currentFragment = new Fragment1();
isMainActivityShown=false;   //when moving to fragment1 
isFragment1FromMainActivity=true;
frgManager = getFragmentManager();
frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, currentFragment)
                                        .commit();
     @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

            if(isMainActivityShown)
            {
                finish();
            }
            else if(isFragment1FromMainActivity)
            {
            isMainActivityShown=true;
            isFragment1FromMainActivity=false;
               //write the code to move to MainActvity
            }
           else if(isFragment1FromFragment2)
            {
               //Code to move back to Fragment2 
          Fragment currentFragment = new Fragment2();
                isFragment2Shown=true;
               isFragment1FromFragment2=false;

                FragmentManager frgManager;
                frgManager = getFragmentManager();
                frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, currentFragment)
                        .commit();
            }
           else if(isFragment2Shown)
            {  //When you are in Fragment 2 pressing back button will move to fragment1
                Fragment currentFragment = new Fragment1();
                isFragment2Shown=false;
               isFragment1FromFragment2=true;

                FragmentManager frgManager;
                frgManager = getFragmentManager();
                frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, currentFragment)
                        .commit();
            }

            }
```

Fragment1

```
Fragment currentFragment = new Fragment2();

MainActivity.isFragment1FromMainActivity=false;

MainActivity.isFragment2Shown=true;
frgManager = getFragmentManager();
frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, currentFragment)
                                    .commit();
```